# How do I create two new Safari windows in different positions?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write a script which opens two Safari windows with different bounds, at different positions on the desktop, like so:

[image: Rough illustration of what I want to do]

The {pixels wide, pixels high} labels are more accurate than the actual proportions of the boxes. The problem I'm having is that I can set the bounds of the window on the left exactly how I want - as it's the first one the script generates - but when I try to specify the bounds of the second window on the right, its position is tied to the position of the first window, and it's either constrained within the bounds of the first window or - if I tell it to "spawn" outside the bounds of the first window - doesn't appear at all.

```
# Desktop: {1280, 800}

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:"https://www.google.com"}
    set bounds of front window to {25, 25, 550, 750}
    make new document with properties {URL:"https://www.google.com"}
    set bounds of front window to {25, 25, 700, 750}
end tell
```

As you'll see, the script currently creates both windows at the same {25, 25} co-ordinate for now as this is the closest functional version I have to what I want.

How can I set the bounds of the second, right-hand window to appear as shown in the image regardless of the bounds of the first window on the left?

Comment: Make the second set of bounds `{600, 25, 1200, 750}`

Comment: @Mark Setchel, RE: "Make the second set of bounds `{600, 25, 1200, 750}`", That would make the second window 600 × 725 pixels, not 700 x 750 as shown in the diagram in the OP. The `bounds` for both _windows_ need to be adjusted in order to have the first one at 550 x 750 pixels in size and the second one 700 x 750 pixels in size with some space around them as shown in the diagram in the OP

Comment: @user3439894 Yes, I realise that, thank you. I was merely demonstrating a set of parameters that show how to get the second window further over to the right rather than worrying about specific placement :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *value* of the `bounds` *property* is returned as a four item *list* of integers representing the *bounding area* of the *window* on the *screen*:

- List item **1**: {`x1`, y1, x2, y2}

  - The distance in pixels from the left side of the screen to the left side of the window.
- List item **2**: {x1, `y1`, x2, y2}

  - The distance in pixels from the top of the screen to the top of the window.
- List item **3**: {x1, y1, `x2`, y2}

  - The distance in pixels from the left side of the screen to the right side of the window.
- List item **4**: {x1, y1, x2, `y2`}

  - The distance in pixels from the top of the screen to the bottom of the window.

The `bounds` for the first *window* with a width of 550 and height of 750 with a 25 pixel offset would be:

```
{25, 25, 575, 775}
```

The `bounds` for the second *window* with a width of 700 and height of 750 and no space between it and the first window would be:

```
{575, 25, 1275, 775}
```

---

This will give you the two *windows* of the sizes show in your diagram, however the spacing is not exactly as shown.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    make new document with properties {URL:"https://www.google.com"}
    set bounds of front window to {25, 25, 575, 775}
    make new document with properties {URL:"https://www.google.com"}
    set bounds of front window to {575, 25, 1275, 775}
end tell
```